# unable to delay the evaluation of code block till run time in chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I have a chef recipe where I want to include a gem file and use it as below

```
gem_package "my-gem"
require '<my-gem>'
my_var = <Using methods supported by gem>
```

However this fails during compilation with error "cannot load such file "
Is there any way I can delay this check so that during the run gem gets installed and can be used.

I don't want to use a ruby block (*Not sure even if that would work or fail during compilation*) , since I am not sure how could I make "my_var" variable available outside the ruby block in other chef-resource or during any conditional checks that are done outside the ruby block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two answers here. First is to the question you asked, you could wrap the code in a `ruby_block` resource. That will delay evaluation until the converge phase.

The real answer to this question is that you should be using a `chef_gem` resource instead of `gem_package`. That automatically installs the gem to Chef's ruby installation and does it at compile time to avoid this problem.

Comment: This solved my issue to an extent. However now I am facing another issue which is seems to be similar. I am trying to use mysql_chef_gem from ChefSuperMarket in my recipe to get mysql gem installed which is followed by require 'mysql' statement in the recipe. However this fails again with same error during converge phase. When I checked mysql_chef_gem I saw that the gem is installed using gem_package and not chef_gem , I changed it to chef_gem for the sake of testing but even after this change, the recipe fails at compile time at require statement.

Comment: Then post a new question for your new issue.